# a:visited links - opacity not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, opacity

I'm trying to make it so that when a link has been visited, it is persistently a certain color AND a certain opacity that matches non-visited links when WebKit fully transitions them.

Using this:

```
a:visited {
    color:#cc7839;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

I can get the visited links to always be that color, except opacity isn't doing anything. I set it to 0.1 to make it easier to see if it was working.

When I hover over a visited link, it transitions to the opaque color set by WebKit for a:link:hover.

Here's the CSS that's in another file for setting all links:

```
a:link:hover,a:hover,a:visited:hover {
    color: #cc7839;
    opacity:0.8;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in; 
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

I'm thinking I have to change something with the latter CSS in terms of which `a` elements it specifies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access nested elements with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114641/access-nested-elements-with-css)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not possible. You can only use the `:visited` selector to change the color of an element. Thus opacity doesn't work.

**SEC7115**

> :visited and :link styles can only differ by color.

[**Reference here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Was unable to find W3 documentation stating it..

Comment: Gotcha.  So there's no way to actually achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @JoshCrozier, It's for security, *not* usability. See https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: @Pacerier Thanks for pointing that out. That's interesting, I'll have to read that article.

Comment: That's a lame solution. Why not just make getComputedStyle() return meaningless info regarding :visited links instead of preventing us from styling them?

Comment: @trusktr I agree.. not really sure why they restrict that information.