# Access nested elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to access nested html elements with CSS to change a few properties, but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
div.someid1 a:visited {
  color: #666666;
}

div.someid2 a:visited img {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<div class="someid1">
  <a href="https://example.com">link</a>
</div>
<div class="someid2">
  <a href="https://example.com">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

The first part of CSS code works perfectly, but that second part doesn't. And it doesn't work with ">" sign as well. I tried to google other different solutions, but none actually works.

Essentially I'm trying to make images inside of visited links to appear gray-ish to indicate that user has already clicked them.

Comment: you'll need to include your HTML so we can see what your CSS is trying to apply to...

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've provided. You need a [mcve]. Preference as a live demo using the stack snippets feature.

Comment: i guess `someid` is an ID

Comment: @TemaniAfif - no, otherwise neither the top or the bottom selector would apply. It is a weird class name, for sure, though!

Comment: `:visited` has a [white-list of available properties that can be changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited), which does not include `opacity`.

Comment: Aha - that's really interesting @chazsolo - [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#Example) specifically states that any alpha/opacity changes will be ignored (so you can't change the alpha of an rgba color either. I guess this is to close a loophole in the 'sniff which links are visited by the user technique'?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the html in the original question. I have now edited it to include the full example.

Comment: You can add `class` on click, and use `session storage` to add those classes back when user has already visited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a:visited links - opacity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215684/avisited-links-opacity-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:visited` pseudo-class [restricts changes to a white-list of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited):

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `border-color`
- `border-bottom-color`
- `border-left-color`
- `border-right-color`
- `border-top-color`
- `column-rule-color`
- `outline-color`

Since `opacity` is not on this list you will not see your image change.

---

[A note on *why* this list is restrictive](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#link):

> Since it is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the user’s consent, UAs may treat all links as unvisited links or implement other measures to preserve the user’s privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

Comment: But is there some alternative way to achieve similar results? (I have just added better explanation of why I'm trying to do that in my original question).

Comment: @NewProger Not that I know of by using an `img`. However, you could 1) replace that with a font-based icon (which can be styled with `color`), however note that alpha values will ignored, or 2) use an SVG and style with `fill` or `stroke`

Comment: @NewProger I think you've hit a dead-end. Browsers have blocked detecting visited links with JavaScript so that's a no-go too. Although you could save 'clicked' action to localstorage and add a class to the element and do what ever you want but too much for such little behaviour? Is it worth it?

Comment: Font is a good suggestion.

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate... but I guess I have no choice, but to abandon this specific approach and do it another way. Thank you everyone for your help!