# Hyper link Color-styling in CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

The hyperlink's initial colour is blue, i.e,, of the visited selector. But the background-colour is black, i.e., of the link selector. Additionally, after visiting the link once, the text colour remains blue as it should be, but the background does not transform to transparent.

**Here is the styling code:**

```html
<style>
a:link {
  color: pink;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: blue;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Link Colors</h2>

<a href="html_images.asp" target="_self">HTML Images</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to understand the behaviour of the link selectors. Why is the formatting unclear, and am getting the random mixed-output from the two different and exclusive selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Visited:** A link when it has already been visited (exists in the browser's history), styled using the `:visited` pseudo-class.

So if you have visited your link at least once it will always be `visited`

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_links).

Comment: If that's the case, then why the background-colour property of the visited pseudo-class does not apply?

Comment: That is because the color of the pseudo-class is transparent, try to change it to some other color.

Comment: Also the `:visited` and `:link` should only differ in color and not in opacity. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh180764(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) SEC7115

Comment: This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215684/avisited-links-opacity-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some background-color to anchor tag and add **link with visited** for visited to work like **a:visited:link**. Try below CSS :

```
a:link {
  color: pink;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited:link {
  color: blue;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: a:visited:link has its own problem. It won’t change the text Color, for here, to blue, but selects that of default visited, i.e., purple. Also, when I add background-colour to the anchor tag, making a pseudo class for visited:link becomes irrelevant.